# Tracking transaction attempts/failed attempts sent to a contract from unknown parties

Tags: solidity, web3js, security, events, monitoring

In light of the recently killed parity library and how the person responsible went around randomly trying to kill contracts, is there a way of monitoring smart contracts for attempted and potentially malicious transactions sent by unknown parties?

- For successful transactions, we can watch for events.  (This helps to monitor and alert for any critical actions, such as `LogOwnerChange` or `LogPayment`)
- If you originate a transaction, you can check for its success by checking
  the transaction receipt. So the sender can check.

**So my question is, is there any way to
   monitor for unknown / random transaction requests/attempts being sent
   to the contract, that have failed?** (other than manually checking Etherscan)